# This release is not compliant with the Google Play 64-bit requirement play developer account

Tags: android, android-ndk

So, I have this old app and I want to publish a new update but in the play store it's showing up this error.

```
This release is not compliant with the Google Play 64-bit requirement.
The following APKs or App Bundles are available to 64-bit devices, but they only have 32-bit native code: [18]
Include 64-bit and 32-bit native code in your app. Use the Android App Bundle publishing format to automatically ensure that each device architecture receives only the native code it needs. This avoids increasing the overall size of your app. Learn More
```

I looked up and didn't find any useful info.

I have this in my Gradle file

`ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86','x86_64'`

This is what is showing up when I'm analyzing my APK.

[image]

Comment: You don't have an x86_64-version of that library. Perhaps no such version is available. Unless you can find or build an x86_64-version you'll have to remove the x86-version.

Comment: @Michael thank you for your advice. How can I do that?

Comment: How to know which library is causing this issue?

Comment: Remove x86 from your abiFilters.